# How to add Server-side Custom Hooks in Gitlab?

Tags: bash, gitlab, githooks, git-push, git-clone

What I am trying to do is that i want to add my hooks to repo in server, so that whoever has cloned the repo, passes through this before pushing to Gitlab server.
So far what i have done is, created *pre-receive* file in custom_hooks folder in **/.git/custom_hooks** and added some script to it.
Below is my pre-receive file.

```
#!/bin/bash

zero_commit="0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
excludeExisting="--not --all"

while read oldrev newrev refname; do
  # echo "payload"
  echo $refname $oldrev $newrev

  # branch or tag get deleted
  if [ "$newrev" = "$zero_commit" ]; then
    continue
  fi

  # Check for new branch or tag
  if [ "$oldrev" = "$zero_commit" ]; then
    span=`git rev-list $newrev $excludeExisting`
  else
    span=`git rev-list $oldrev..$newrev $excludeExisting`
  fi

  for COMMIT in $span;
  do
    for FILE  in `git log -1 --name-only --pretty=format:'' $COMMIT`;
    do
        echo "rejecting all pushes"
        exit 1
    done
  done
done
exit 0
```

Then I cloned the repo in my local Windows machine and tried pushing it. But it didnt create the intended effect. It still got pushed to server.

I'm new to Gitlab and Git Hooks. I don't know whether my *pre-receive* file is wrong or where I am going wrong. Please let me how to add hooks to server so that it validates/works for whoever cloned my repo.
Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

See https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks which starts with:

Like many other Version Control Systems, Git has a way to fire off custom scripts when certain important actions occur. There are two groups of these hooks: client-side and server-side. Client-side hooks are triggered by operations such as committing and merging, while server-side hooks run on network operations such as receiving pushed commits. You can use these hooks for all sorts of reasons.

See also https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/server_hooks.html

Comment: can please tell me how to make it executable?

Comment: `sudo chmod +x /path/to/hook` where `/path/to/hook` is the full path to the hook file.